# Rally: get Task Remaining Total

Tags: rally

I've started to develop custom HTML report in Rally and I need to get somehow TASK REMAINING TOTAL. I can see it changes in description field of model "ArtifactNotification" (like: "description:  TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from [19.0] to [21.0], TASK REMAINING TOTAL changed from [18.0] to [20.0]"), but I can't find a proper model in Rally.data.wsapi.store for making a reference to it and get a number of remaining hours.

Model 'Task' does not have it.

Probably somebody knows where is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppSDK2 model 'task' does not have it because 
`TaskEstimateTotal`, 
`TaskRemainingTotal` exist on user story object in Web Services API. Please see [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) documentation, specifically HierarchicalRequirement (a.k.a user story) in the Object Model. The values for those attributes on a user story are read only and roll up from `Estimate` and `ToDo` attributes of  individual tasks.

Comment: HierarchicalRequirement appeared to be exactly what I needed!